# Debian Jessie (Minibian) cannot connect to WiFi?

Tags: debian, wifi, raspbian, wpa-supplicant, wpa2

I have two brand new Raspberry Pi 3s both running Minibian. I am trying to use the built-in WiFi adapater to connect to my server subnet.

I can see the network I'm attempting to connect to with `iwlist scan`. The network I am attempting to connect to is WPA2 personal. It is setup to only use AES and not TKIP. This is what the `/etc/network/interfaces` file looks like...

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
        wpa-ssid Allen_Hundley
        wpa_psk MY_HASHED_PSK
        wpa-pairwise CCMP
        wpa-group CCMP
        wpa-proto RSN
        wpa-key-mgmt WPA-PSK
```

One issue I'm thinking may be there is the underscore in my SSID. But I have been unable to find any information on this.

What could the issue be?